# Missing PDO Driver for SQLite

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, pdo

I created a droplet in DigitalOcean (LAMP on Ubuntu 20.04)
Installed WP PHP files using WinSCP
Run it on PUTTY
Checked site on web browser

I received a message saying "PDO Driver for SQLite is missing"

Found solutions online and here's what I've tried:

1. Find php.ini & uncomment (remove ;) on extension=pdo_mysql & extension=pdo_sqlite
2. Restarted apache on PuTTY by using this command sudo service apache2 restart

But didn't work

Any tips please?